# How to overwrite a file of nodemobules on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want to overwrite a file of nodemobules on Heroku using the following npm script.

What should I do to find the location of the file?

replaceScript.js

```
const data = "fixedcode";
fs.writeFile('LOCATION_PATH_OF_A_FILE_OF_HEROKU_NODE_MODULE', data, (err) => 
{console.log("soxError",err);
});
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"postinstall": "node replaceScript.js"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__dirname` to get the location of the `replaceScript`, and from there, navigate around to `node_modules` and to the nested file. For example, if `replaceScript` is in the same directory as `node_modules`:

```
// replaceScript.js

// The following test will pass when on Heroku:
if (process.env._ && process.env._.includes('heroku')) {
    const path = `${__dirname}/node_modules/some-package/index.js`;
    require('fs').writeFileSync(path, data);
}
```